# Why is dedicated server cheaper than Cloud VPS?

Tags: vps, dedicated-server, ovh

I need to scale my infrastructure and do not really understand why on my provider (OVH), [dedicated server](https://www.ovh.co.uk/dedicated_servers/rise/rise-1/) seems to be a better value than a [cloud VPS instance](https://www.ovh.co.uk/public-cloud/prices/).

For ~55€ you can get a dedicated server with 4 cores and 32 GB ram

For ~42€ you only get 4 cores and 15 GB ram on cloud instances

This makes me want to switch to dedicated rather than cloud instances, so I'm wondering if I'm missing out on something.. Are there some obvious pros for Cloud vs Dedicated? For instance, in terms of availability, would Cloud be "safer", as it doesn't rely on a single machine?

Comment: It is not particularly useful for us to speculate on the pricing schemes of a particular provider. Price changes rapidly and for non-technical reasons. Try both services, and other providers. Verify they meet your requirements for availability, features, performance, and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the amount of resources needed fixed - you dont get to purchase what you want as you need it and scale up and down. This also requires less infrastructure to support, less redundancy etc.

(That, and the cloud is overpriced).

Cloud is "safer" because if hardware dies its not a major - although you can mitigate against this with RAID and backups, or a deployment pipeline.